React Native Gifted Charts Styling
i'm new with React Native Gifted Charts and i'm trying to make some styles with it. IMAGE
I have question about styling curve line chart.
Thank you all!
My code looks like:
<LineChart
            {...generateProps}
            width={width}
            height={moderateScale(170)}
            noOfSections={5}
            initialSpacing={moderateScale(20)}
            // showVerticalLines
            // yAxisLabelWidth={0}
            // hideYAxisText
            yAxisTextStyle={{
              fontSize: moderateScale(14) / fontScalingFactor,
              color: Colors.BoldBorder,
            }}
            spacing={width / ((generateProps as ChartProps).data.length + (0.005 * (generateProps as ChartProps).data.length / 2))}
            yAxisLabelWidth={moderateScale(25)}
            areaChart
            xAxisLabelTextStyle={{ color: Colors.BoldBorder, fontSize: moderateScale(14) / fontScalingFactor, marginLeft: -moderateScale(10) }}
            xAxisLabelsHeight={moderateScale(14)}
            hideDataPoints
            adjustToWidth
            endFillColor={Colors.White}
            startOpacity={0.5}
            endOpacity={0.3}
            rulesType={'solid'}
            showVerticalLines
            verticalLinesColor={'rgba(127,127,127,0.14)'}
            backgroundColor="transparent"
            rulesColor={'rgba(127,127,127,0.15)'}
            curved
            xAxisType='dashed'
            yAxisColor="transparent"
            xAxisColor="transparent"
          />

Is it possible to add some padding maybe? I don't like the trimmed ends at the bottom and top.

You can use the overflowTop and overflowBottom props.
